# How do I return strings from an asynchronous POST request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

I'm trying to add a signup function, using a controller and a factory, to my Angular app, but I haven't been able to get several strings (tied conditionally to success or failure) to return from my factory to my controller.

The return statements below only return empty strings at first (I assume this has to do with the asynchronous http, but am not sure). In any case, how would I return the two strings I desire (_alertType and _alertMessage) with the updated values from .success or .error?

signup.html

```html
<div class="col-md-6 container-fluid">

  <div class="jumbotron text-center" ng-controller="SignupController as vm">

    <p class="lead">
      <h2>Account Creation</h2>
      Welcome! Please make an account
    </p>

    <form ng-submit="vm.signup()">
      <p><input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username or Email" ng-model="username"></p>
      <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password" ng-model="password"></p>
      <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="commit" value="Sign Up"></p>
      <alert ng-show="vm.alertMessage" type="{{ vm.alertType }}">{{ vm.alertMessage }}</alert>
    </form>

  </div>

</div>
```

signup.factory.js

```
(function() {

  angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('signupFactory', signupFactory);

  signupFactory.$inject = ['$http'];

  function signupFactory($http) {
    var _alertType = '';
    var _alertMessage = '';
    var service = {
      signup: signup,
      getAlertType: getAlertType,
      getAlertMessage: getAlertMessage
    };
    return service;

    function signup(username, password) {

      var request = $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/user',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: {
          username: username,
          password: password
        }
      });
      request.success(function(){
        _alertType = "success";
        _alertMessage = "Signed Up";
      });
      request.error(function(){
        _alertType = "danger";
        _alertMessage = "Signup Failed";
      });
    }

    function getAlertType() {
      return _alertType;
    }

    function getAlertMessage() {
      return _alertMessage;
    }

  }

})();
```

signup.controller.js

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('SignupController', SignupController);

  SignupController.$inject = ['$scope', 'signupFactory'];

  function SignupController($scope, signupFactory) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.signup = function() {
      signupFactory.signup($scope.username, $scope.password);
      vm.alertMessage = signupFactory.getAlertMessage();
      vm.alertType = signupFactory.getAlertType();
    }

  }
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look for [promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

```
var promise = asyncGreet('Robin Hood');
promise.then(function(greeting) {
  alert('Success: ' + greeting);
}, function(reason) {
  alert('Failed: ' + reason);
});
```

Comment: That looks promising! (sorry) I'll check it out and report back if I can use it solve my problem, thanks!

Comment: You can find sample code here http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/using-an-angularjs-factory-to-interact-with-a-restful-service

Comment: Huh, he actually has pretty much the same thing I do, except he puts the .success and .error statements in the controller and take them out of the factory entirely. I think I read somewhere that you shouldn't put logic in your controllers but that's starting to sound like a false memory :P